# What Does The Name Ahnaf Mean?

Tags: naming, names, baby

Assalamualaikum, I came across this unique and beautiful name while searching for unique sahaba names , and was pleased to see in another website that it means “worshiper of Allah“. Wikipedia is showing that Al-ahnaf(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnaf_ibn_Qais) means the clubfooted.

Do Ahnaf and Al-ahnaf mean same?

Kindly explain as I have already kept my baby’s name Ahnaf Islam.

Comment: http://arabiclexicon.hawramani.com/%d8%ad%d9%86%d9%81/#1382b0

Answer (score 1):

The word "Ahnaf" refers to a man who has a particular crookedness in his legs. The Sahabi was named like that because he had such a crookedness.

As far as I found, it does not mean "worshiper of Allah."

Comment: So, should name be changed? Is it forbidden to keep this name?

Comment: Lots of palces, they have suggested this name for muslim baby boy: https://parenting.firstcry.com/articles/100-best-sahabi-baby-boy-names-with-meanings/

Comment: However, i have also found this http://companions.hawramani.com/?s=Ahnaf